# Access user's info domain or username and login into web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I m developing an asp.net web api and have to access user details from LDAP.
Sentcha is used to create an app that is using this api,what I want that is user can access or log-in inito this api using windows authentication.
Please let me know .

Comment: I'm not an expert in this but it feels like you haven't given us enough details to answer.

Comment: We are currently developing a tablet application based on asp.net WEB API 1 (MVC) and the web methods returning JSON response will be consumed to get the front end(created using sentcha) working by making service calls to the tablet app.Need to know that in such a disintegrated system how can we make Intranet login work. and how will the LDAP authentication will happen so that if a user is intranet user has gets auto logged in the application.

Any suggestions how can this be achieved?